# Best Way To Convert All "SMALLINT" Columns Within A Database Schema To "BIT"? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How do I convert all `smallint` type columns from my database to `bit` types?
I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Edited your question content, sorry but saying title says it all doesn't help people.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio.  Says it all.  *[Right click on the table, enter design mode, make your changes; then SSMS handles the messy bit for you.]*

Comment: The Op is asking for all of the columns in all of the tables in the schema - this could be hundreds.  Doing manually could therefore be very lengthy, error prone, etc.  And I presume the reason for the question.  See my answer for one way to do it via a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do it with `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column [new_datatype]`.

Be careful of things like default values because I haven't tested with them.

Example 1 - will give a list of queries for you to review / amend / execute (safer option).

```
DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @FromDataType NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ToDataType NVARCHAR(50)

SET @TableSchema = 'dbo';
SET @FromDataType = 'smallint';
SET @ToDataType = 'bit';

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema 
       AND TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams' 
       AND DATA_TYPE = @FromDataType

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + N' ALTER COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + N' ' + @ToDataType -- + CHAR(13) + N'GO'
    PRINT @Query

    EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @Query

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Example 2 - will execute (recommend running example 1 first!)

```
DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @FromDataType NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ToDataType NVARCHAR(50)

SET @TableSchema = 'dbo';
SET @FromDataType = 'smallint';
SET @ToDataType = 'bit';

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema 
       AND TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams' 
       AND DATA_TYPE = @FromDataType

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + N' ALTER COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + N' ' + @ToDataType + CHAR(13) + N' GO'
    PRINT @Query

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful doing this and test it on a backup database first.  The following query will create ALTER statements for each column in your database that have SMALLINT datatype to convert them to BIT.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(o.Name) + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.Name) + ' BIT' as Command
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.columns c
on o.object_id = c.object_id
where system_type_id = 52
and o.Type = 'U'
```

Also, be sure each column listed only contains 1 or 0 or you will get truncation errors when you run the script.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about converting the column data type, I don't thing you can do that directly.  You can add a new column as BIT and populate it from the old column, then drop the old column and rename the new one back to the old name.

See the [online docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Can be done in SQL Server 2008 with ALTER TABLE and ALTER COLUMN.

Comment: @Pete - I'll defer to your expertise, but my reading of the documentation suggests that you cannot alter a column to a dimension smaller than the source.

Comment: You can in this case, but if you do, your data may be truncated.  I am assuming the smallint values will be a 0 or a 1 for this scenario.